# Multiple Membership Provider in web.config

Tags: asp.net-membership

I've a WCF web the config file which requires multiple membership provider due to reason below:
 1. One membership for WCF which uses application A.
 e.g.

```
<add name="MySqlMembershipProvider1"
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             applicationName="ApplicationA"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             requiresUniqueEmail="true"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
```

1. The other membership for creating and updating asp.net users.

> ```
> <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider2"
>                  connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
>                  applicationName="ApplicationB"
>                  requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
>                  requiresUniqueEmail="true"
>                  type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
> ```
>
> />

How do I specify the provider name on above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlMembershipProvider p1 = SqlMembershipProvider)
Membership.Providers["MySqlMembershipProvider1"];
....//
```

then using the membership providers's instance p1 for Application you can do whatever you need

```
SqlMembershipProvider p2 = (SqlMembershipProvider)
Membership.Providers["MySqlMembershipProvider2"];
....//
```

please see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovidercollection.item.aspx)